# How can I get a string literal (character array?) from a value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google App Script to grab text from a Google Sheet, then upload it to Firebase. JSON encoding of any data from the sheet is adding extra escape characters that I don't need. I am trying to figure out a way to prevent this because it does not add unnecessary escape characters if I use a string literal.

This function below is what I call to sync data from the sheet to firebase. I initialize an object from the gathered data, and then I send it off to the Firebase database for updating.

If I keep it as it is, the string at `data[i][1]` eventually has escape characters automatically added in. If I replace `data[i][1]` with any literal string (i.e. `"Testing\n\n-Caleb"`) the value of that key keeps its entire string un-modified.

```
// Gets the data from the sheet and puts it in an object.
// It is called by running the sync button in the sheet.
function sync() {
  // get the spreadsheet data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("main");
  var [rows, columns] = [sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()];
  var data = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows, columns);

  // put the data in an object
  testAlert(data[1][1]);   // prints "Testing
                           //        
                           //         -Caleb"                   (OK)
  var obj = {}
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj[i - 1] = {
      Happy: data[i][0],
      Meh: data[i][1],             // THE VALUE OF TOPIC
    //Meh: "Testing\n\n-Caleb"     // THE LITERAL STRING OPTION
      Down: data[i][2],
      Sad: data[i][3],
      Angry: data[i][4]
    }
  }
  testAlert(obj[0].Meh).   // prints "Testing
                           //        
                           //         -Caleb"                   (OK)

  // convert to unused JSON object to print to the window what is happening
  var jsonOBJ = JSON.stringify(obj[0].Meh)
  testAlert(jsonOBJ).      // prints "\"Testing\\n\\n-Caleb\"" (ERROR)

  updateFirebaseData(obj, "emotions");
}
```

This is the function called at the end:

```
// updates the firebase database with specified data and location
function updateFirebaseData(obj, loc) {
  var firebaseUrl = "https://gem-0-2.firebaseio.com/";
  var secret = "FirebaseSecret";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, secret);
  var result = base.updateData(loc, obj);
}
```

The data at `data[i][1]` is "Testing\n\n-Caleb" and by the time it reaches the database, it is "\"Testing\n\n-Caleb\"", and so escaped characters that I intentionally place, like end-lines, aren't translated properly. However, if I put "Testing\n\n-Caleb" as the value for "Meh", then it stays as-is.

Comment: You're calling `JSON.stringify()`, so you're converting the string to JSON format.

Comment: I am calling ```JSON.stringify()``` for testing purposes. The actual ```updataData(loc,obj)``` call ends up converting it to a JSON object anyway, and since I can't see the result afterward unless I look at Firebase, I do this to immediately see the results on the sheet.

Comment: If it's adding JSON encoding when it stores in Firebase, I'd expect it to decode it when retrieving. If you look at Firebase manually, you need to do that yourself, by calling `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: I updated the last sentence of my question to clarify. As I request the data from firebase, it grabs the key just fine, but the escape characters are messed up. Is there something I can do to improve my question?

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. A string is the same whether it was created from a literal or returned by an API. When you call Firebase, it can't decide to encode it as JSON in one case and not the other, because it can't tell the difference.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I believe I misunderstood what kind of object was created from ```var data = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows, columns);``` Your earlier ```JSON.parse(data[i][1])``` answer was correct. Will you post it again and explain why the value at ```data[i][1]``` needs to be parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sheet.getSheetValues()` is returning a string that's already encoded as JSON. If you want to store the actual string, you need to decode it with `JSON.parse()`.

```
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj[i - 1] = {
      Happy: data[i][0],
      Meh: JSON.parse(data[i][1]),             // THE VALUE OF TOPIC
      Down: data[i][2],
      Sad: data[i][3],
      Angry: data[i][4]
    }
```